# Sending a string that contains quotations to a file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, append, quotation-marks

I am trying to use VBA build a .jet file, but when I try to append, two possible problems appear.  Either it includes all double quotes including the double double quotes like you would normally do in, say, a msgbox, or the string wont work if i remove the double double quotes because the first instance of quotes terminates the string.  An example of my code is below (note, the commented/indented areas in the main sub are various possibilities I have tried but without success:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
Dim MyStr As String
  'MyStr = "{" & Chr(34) & "myid" & Chr(34) & ":345," & Chr(34) & "content" & Chr(34) & ":["
  'MyStr = "{""myid"":345,""content"":["

  'appendToFile ("{""myid"":345,""content"":[")
  'appendToFile (MyStr)
End Sub


Sub appendToFile(MyStr As String)
Dim fileName As String
 fileName = "MyFile.jet"
Open Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName For Append As #1
    Write #1, MyStr
Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see where you are showing your desired result. Or what happened with the append operation when you tried your various attempts.

Comment: ok, so for example, it will say this in MyFile.jet when i append: "{""myid"":345,""content"":["

Comment: And what do you want it to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the extra quotes appearing in your `.jet`, you can `append` using the `Print #` statement, and not the `Write #` statement.

*Unlike the `Print #` statement, the `Write #` statement inserts commas between items and **quotation marks around strings** as they are written to the file.*

For example, this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ject()
Dim MyStr As String
  
  MyStr = "{" & Chr(34) & "myid" & Chr(34) & ":345," & Chr(34) & "content" & Chr(34) & ":["
  
  appendToFile (MyStr)
End Sub


Sub appendToFile(MyStr As String)
Dim fileName As String
 fileName = "MyFile.jet"
Open Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & fileName For Append As #1
    Print #1, MyStr 
Close #1
End Sub
```

will result in:

```
{"myid":345,"content":[
```

when opening the .jet file with a text editor.

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes!  That is exactly what I needed.  It works! Thank you very much.

Comment: any ideas on how to delete the last character in a file?  for example, I want to delete the comma in a textfile that ends in ...potato"]},

Comment: @BrandonRedmond There are any number of methods to do that, but not something that can be answered in a comment. If you are having problems, post it as a new question. Include your efforts at accomplishing it, along with enough usable data that someone can reproduce any problem you ran into. Might help to take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).